What's a good grease for sliding bathroom cubicle doors?
My bathroom cube doors had some dust and grime in the tracks. I cleaned them with anti-mold spray that messed up their lubrication and caused the doors to get stuck.
I made a second mistake and applied WD40 spray to fix the lubrication. It made things worse since now the wheels are sliding and slipping in the tracks.
What's the right kind of sticky grease that's suitable for this condition?


WD-40 is a "water displacer" i.e. the wrong thing.  Perhaps try a silicone spray lube?

If you do want to use a grease, almost any grease should work; this is not a high precision device. I would suggest lithium grease, but that's because that's what I keep on hand rather than my knowing any reason why it would be better for this purpose than anything else.
